# private vs final как метка "этот метод нельзя переопределить"

Tags: java, инкапсуляция

Создавая класс мы проектируем его таким образом, чтобы классы-наследники могли с ним работать через специальный интерфейс публичных методов. Скрытую реализацию мы помечаем как `private`. Но как понять, что лучше использовать - `private` или `final`? И осмысленно ли применение обоих?

Comment: `final` модификатор запрещает любое переопределение. Не важно что это - метод или поле. Пользоваться им можно, но переопределить нет. `private` в свою очередь - это определение области видимости поля или метода. Как вам описали ниже - это совсем разные вещи. Если вы хотите с помощью `private` защитить метод от переопределения, то это не самый лучший вариант.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы правы в одном - как `final`, так и `private` - оба не дают вам переопределить метод в наследнике.

Однако предназначение у них совершенно разное. Это как сравнивать машину и самолёт только потому, что у них есть колёса.

А теперь пример. Что, если вы хотите сделать открытый (`public`) метод, но без возможности переопределения? `private` вам тут не поможет.

Пусть будет класс `Dog` и класс `Bulldog` (и вы не хотите, чтобы в подклассе класса `Dog` можно было изменить количество ног собаки, ведь все собаки с 4-мя ногами, верно?):

```
public class Dog {
    public final int getLegsCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

public class Bulldog extends Dog {

}
```

И в вашей программе вы всегда сможете получить количество ног собаки, будь то бульдог или просто некая абстрактная собака:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.getLegsCount();

Dog bulldog = new Bulldog();
bulldog.getLegsCount();

Bulldog bulldog2 = new Bulldog();
bulldog2.getLegsCount();
```

Хоть вы и можете получить количество ног, но вы не можете сделать собаку с 3-мя ногами, к примеру.

С другой стороны - пометь вы метод `getLegsCount()` как `private`, а не `public final`, вы бы не смогли вызвать его в вашей программе (вне класса `Dog`).

Comment: Вооот. Шикарный ответ. Спасибо)